# Sum of functions is big Oh

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I want to show that if
$$
d(n) \in O(f(n)) \ \Rightarrow d(n) \le c_1*f(n)   \\ e(n) \in  O(g(n))\Rightarrow e(n) \le c_2 *g(n) \\
$$
then
$$
d(n) +e(n) \in O(f(n)+g(n))
$$
Can I say that (A)
$$
d(n) +e(n) \le (c_1*f(n))+(c_2*g(n)) \ \forall \ n\ge n_1 +n_2 \text{ and } c_1,c_2 >0
$$
or (B)
$$
2*\max(d(n), e(n)) \le c*(g(n)+f(n)) \ \forall  \ n \ge \max(n_1, n_2) \text{ and } c\ge2
$$
Is either of the two considered a proof?

Comment: You can say that $d(n)+e(n)\leq C(f(n)+g(n))~\forall~n\geq\max(n_1,n_2)$ where $C=\max(c_1,c_2)$

Comment: Both proofs are invalid. The first does not establish the thesis and the second doesn't find a suitable $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge n_1,n_2$, we obviously have

$$d(n)+e(n)\le c_1f(n)+c_2g(n)\le\max(c_1,c_2)(f(n)+g(n)),$$ which establishes the claim, in a constructive way.

Comment: why exactly do you choose max(c1,c2)?

Comment: Because you need a constant larger than both $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The option which is more correct is (B): however, for the sake of rigour, putting $c=\max\{c_1,c_2\}$, the proof should be as below
$$
\begin{split}
d(n)+e(n)&\le c_1\cdot f(n)+c_2\cdot g(n)\\ &\le c\cdot f(n) +c\cdot g(n)\\&=c\cdot\big(f(n)+g(n)\big)\\
&\Updownarrow\\
d(n)+e(n) &\in O\big(f(n)+g(n)\big)
\end{split}\quad \forall n\in \Bbb N
$$